# How to correctly setup custom constructors using Codedom

Tags: c#, constructor, codedom

I am trying to get Codedom to generate the following code:

```
public class NewContext : DbContext
{

    public NewContext()
        : base("NewContext")
    {
        EntityToRegisterDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Assembly>();
    }

    static NewContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<EFEntityModelContext>());
    }
}
```

I can generate

```
public class NewContext : DbContext
```

without any problems. I'm running into problems with writing the code that creates the two constructors. I have created two methods, one method for each constructor. This is what my methods look like:

```
public static CodeConstructor BaseStringConstructor(string connectionStr)
{
    CodeConstructor baseStringConstructor = new CodeConstructor();
    baseStringConstructor.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public;
    baseStringConstructor.BaseConstructorArgs.Add(new CodeVariableReferenceExpression("\"connectionStr\""));
    CodeAssignStatement body = new CodeAssignStatement();
    body.Left = new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(), "EntityToRegisterDictionary");
    body.Right = new CodeObjectCreateExpression("ConcurrentDictionary<string, Assembly>");
    baseStringConstructor.Statements.Add(body);
    return baseStringConstructor;
}

public static CodeConstructor StaticInitializerConstructor()
{
    CodeConstructor constructor = new CodeConstructor();
    constructor.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Static;
    CodeObjectCreateExpression body = new CodeObjectCreateExpression("Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<EFEntityModelContext>");            
    constructor.Statements.Add(body);
    return constructor;
}
```

This code doesn't produce exactly the code I want above, however. I get:

```
public NewContext() : 
        base("connectionStr")
{
    .EntityToRegisterDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Assembly>();
}

NewContext()
{
    new Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<EFEntityModelContext>();
}
```

The problem in the "public NewContext()" constructor is that there is a '.' before

```
EntityToRegisterDictionary
```

I assume this is because of the line

```
body.Left = new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(), "EntityToRegisterDictionary");
```

Does anyone know how to make it without the period?

There are three problems with the "static NewContext()" constructor:

1. Codedom doesn't write static before NewContext()
2. It writes new before Database.
3. I can't add a right parenthesis after the () at the end because () is added automatically after whatever I write.

Does anyone know how to just make it write

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<EFEntityModelContext>());
```

without the new keyword and with the addition right parenthesis?

Edit: By the way, EntityToRegisterDictionary is something I define below as:

```
public IDictionary<string, Assembly> EntityToRegisterDictionary { get; private set; }
```

I just haven't included all of this context class.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem in the "public NewContext()" constructor is that there is a '.' before

Yes, you are providing a `CodeFieldReferenceExpression` with no actual field reference so it's just using an empty string. What you're looking for is [`CodeThisReferenceExpression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codethisreferenceexpression(v=vs.110).aspx) since you're just accessing a member on the same class.

```
body.Left = new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(new CodeThisReferenceExpression(), "EntityToRegisterDictionary");
```

This will generate the assignment using the `this` keyword as shown below:

```
this.EntityToRegisterDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Assembly>();
```

---

> Codedom doesn't write static before NewContext()

You are using `CodeConstructor` which creates an *instance* constructor. The fact that one of the attributes you can provide is `MemberAttributes.Static` is a little misleading, but it becomes clear when you read the remarks section of the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codeconstructor(v=vs.110).aspx). You should be using [`CodeTypeConstructor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codetypeconstructor(v=vs.110).aspx) to generate a `static` constructor.

---

> It writes new before Database.
>   I can't add a right parenthesis after the () at the end because () is added automatically after whatever I write.

You are using [`CodeObjectCreateExpression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codeobjectcreateexpression(v=vs.110).aspx), which is used to create a new instance of a type, to try and call a `static` method. To call a method, you would use `CodeMethodInvokeExpression`. You should first create an expression for the `Database.SetInitializer` method and pass the argument using `CodeObjectCreateExpression`.

```
var method = new CodeMethodReferenceExpression(new CodeTypeReferenceExpression("Database"), "SetInitializer");
var body = new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(method, new CodeObjectCreateExpression("DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<EFEntityModelContext>"));
constructor.Statements.Add(body);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CodeAssignStatement body = new CodeAssignStatement();
body.Left = new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(null, "Propiedad ");
body.Right = new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(null, "parametro");

------------------------------- OUTPUT--------------------------------
private Metodo(string parametro) {
    Propiedad = parametro;
}
```